# GeoServer PostGIS layer with mixed SRS possible?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, geoserver

I'd like to setup a layer in GeoServer based on a table in PostGIS DB. The geometry column in the table has no SRID set (Find_SRID for this table returns 0).
Geometries inserted into the table don't have the same SRID. Is it still possible to create a GeoServer layer from this table?

When I try to setup the layer, GeoServer sets "Native SRS" to one of the SRS present in the table data and I cannot remove it.

If its not possible, is the some possibility in GeoServer to serve global GIS data with mixed SRS?

Comment: It's poor practice to load data with varying SRIDs in a single table, and an antipattern to load data without any spatial reference at all. Rather than going forward with effectively corrupt data, you'd probably be best off re-loading the data with a single correct spatial reference (reprojecting as necessary once, instead of each time the data is accessed), which will make all your other steps significantly easier.

Comment: As @vince says don't do this, it won't work and geoserver will produce random data

Comment: just to understand you, mixed SRS in DB is not data without spatial reference, or corrupt data, so what u mean with this?
I guess, GeoServer than cannot do what i would hope: take the mixed SRS data and reproject it into a common projection i specify in e.g. WMS "srs" parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is stated here:

> The geometry column in the table has no SRID set (Find_SRID for this table returns 0).

As a result GeoServer considers this unprojected data (it's just numbers not a position) and can't reproject it. GeoServer only considers the SRS of the geometry column not the individual projection of the geometries (which PostGIS doesn't return in a normal query) so can not process a column of this type correctly.

Spatial database tables should have a **single** enforced SRS (SRID) not a random mix, you can achieve this by reprojecting your random polygons to a common SRS **before** adding them to the database. GeoServer will then happily import and reproject your data to any SRS that is requested.

Comment: now i understand, thx a lot! but for a global GIS system which needs to keep precision, reprojecting data is for sure not good. could u point out some suggestions, how to store the data, or even maybe post some links to concepts of global GIS systems?

Comment: If it's truly global then use WGS84 (or similar), but more likely you have a number of projects scattered around the world.

Comment: yeah, scattered around the world and u can jump from one to other ....

Comment: then many tables is the best plan